# Oracle will not start after VM crash

Tags: oracle

My Oracle 11gR2, running on a VM, crashed when the datastore of the host filled up. I got the VM to start and as I'm trying to start the DB, I see this:

```
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1987563520 bytes
Fixed Size                  2229704 bytes
Variable Size            1476397624 bytes
Database Buffers          503316480 bytes
Redo Buffers                5619712 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Process ID: 3929
Session ID: 1 Serial number: 5
```

The alert log contains this:

```
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 1615598463
Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Completed: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Fri Nov 05 12:43:47 2021
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
Beginning crash recovery of 1 threads
Started redo scan
Completed redo scan
 read 5129 KB redo, 867 data blocks need recovery
Started redo application at
 Thread 1: logseq 16580, block 11139
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 2 Seq 16580 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo02.log
Completed redo application of 2.76MB
Completed crash recovery at
 Thread 1: logseq 16580, block 21398, scn 406093127
 867 data blocks read, 860 data blocks written, 5129 redo k-bytes read
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 16581 (thread open)
Thread 1 opened at log sequence 16581
  Current log# 3 seq# 16581 mem# 0: /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo03.log
Successful open of redo thread 1
MTTR advisory is disabled because FAST_START_MTTR_TARGET is not set
SMON: enabling cache recovery
[3929] Successfully onlined Undo Tablespace 2.
Undo initialization finished serial:0 start:4294873730 end:4294873790 diff:60 (0 seconds)
Verifying file header compatibility for 11g tablespace encryption..
Verifying 11g file header compatibility for tablespace encryption completed
SMON: enabling tx recovery
Database Characterset is AL32UTF8
No Resource Manager plan active
replication_dependency_tracking turned off (no async multimaster replication found)
Starting background process QMNC
Process QMNC died, see its trace file
Errors in file /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3929.trc:
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Errors in file /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3929.trc:
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Errors in file /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3929.trc:
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Error 450 happened during db open, shutting down database
USER (ospid: 3929): terminating the instance due to error 450
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 3929
ORA-1092 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE OPEN...
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (3929) as a result of ORA-1092
Fri Nov 05 12:43:51 2021
ORA-1092 : opitsk aborting process
```

The trace file for QNMC shows this:

```
*** 2021-11-05 12:43:48.343
Completed recovery checkpoint
----- Recovery Hash Table Statistics ---------
Hash table buckets = 262144
Longest hash chain = 1
Average hash chain = 867/867 = 1.0
Max compares per lookup = 1
Avg compares per lookup = 26276/32586 = 0.8
----------------------------------------------
Recovery sets nab of thread 1 seq 16580 to 21398 with 8 zeroblks
kwqmnich: current time:: 10: 43: 48: 0
kwqmnich: instance no 0 repartition flag 1
kwqmnich: initialized job cache structure

*** 2021-11-05 12:43:49.876
Process QMNC is dead (pid=3931 req_ver=1 cur_ver=1 state=KSOSP_SPAWNED).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trace Bucket Dump Begin: default bucket for process 19 (osid: 3929)
TIME(*=approx):SEQ:COMPONENT:FILE@LINE:FUNCTION:SECT/DUMP: [EVENT#:PID:SID] DATA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-11-05 12:43:48.876672 :80035B07:db_trace:ksb.c@2342:ksbs1p_real(): [10254:19:1] KSBS1P: process USER trying to start background QMNC
2021-11-05 12:43:48.876675 :80035B08:db_trace:ksb.c@2405:ksbs1p_real(): [10254:19:1] KSBS1P: process USER obtained PR enqueue to start background QMNC
2021-11-05 12:43:49.876615 :80035B3A:db_trace:ksb.c@2609:ksbs1p_real(): [10254:19:1] KSBS1P: out of loop: process did not start
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trace Bucket Dump End: default bucket for process 19 (osid: 3929)
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start

*** 2021-11-05 12:43:49.900
USER (ospid: 3929): terminating the instance due to error 450
```

I was thinking of running a "startup mount" followed by a "recover database" but I don't want to take any chances.

Please help me get the database to start.